# Upgrade from Ubuntu Server 9.10 to 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-9.10

Is there a best practice, meaning a particular script or procedure, that should be used to update from one version of Ubuntu Server to another? This would have to be without overwriting files/Apache sites living on the server. Is this something that could be done through Aptitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing: Make a backup. Then follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LucidUpgrades) documentation, which took me less than a minute to find.

Comment: Thanks, I realize Ubuntu has great documentation, was just asking for some feedback on best practices in case  there were recommendations outside the community docs. This content has led me astray in the past, albeit on more convoluted issues, but either way, thanks for pointing me in that direction.